# FullCalendar not displaying data asp.net core razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fullcalendar, razor-pages

I am trying to create a FullCalendar app in Asp.net Core Razor Pages using Visual Studio 2019, but it do not display any data. I would like to click on a date and enter an event in a pop-up dialog box.

index.cshtml:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
   
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/moment.js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>

    <link href='~/fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='~/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  
 <script src='~/fullcalendar/core/main.js'></script>
    <script src='~/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js'></script>

    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
            });

            calendar.render();
        });

    </script>

       <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"
          rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css"
          type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
 
  <script>
        <link href="~/lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" rel='stylesheet' />
  </script>    
        <script src="~/lib/moment.js/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});

            })
        </script>
   
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <br />
                <div id="bootstrapModalFullCalendar"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModalSave" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Save Event</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                        <input type="hidden" id="hdEventID" value="0" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <input type="text" id="txtTitle" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>StartDate</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" id="dtp1">
                                <input type="text" id="txtStartDate" class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" id="divEndDate" style="display:none">
                            <label>EndDate</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" id="dtp2">
                                <input type="text" id="txtEndDate" class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <textarea id="txtDescription" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Theme Color</label>
                            <select id="ddThemeColor" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Default</option>
                                <option value="red">Red</option>
                                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                                <option value="black">Black</option>
                                <option value="green">Green</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.print.css"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var events = [];
            var selectedEvent = null;
            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
            function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
                events = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/home/GetEvents",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                eventID: v.EventID,
                                title: v.Title,
                                description: v.Description,
                                startdate: moment(v.Start),
                                enddate: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                                color: v.ThemeColor,
                            });
                        })

                        GenerateCalender(events);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('failed');
                    }
                })
            }

            function GenerateCalendar(events) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    contentHeight: 400,
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: '#378006',
                    events: events,
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        selectedEvent = calEvent;
                        $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                        var $description = $('<div/>');
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>StartDate:</b>' + calEvent.startdate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a")));
                        if (calEvent.end != null) {
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>EndDate:</b>' + calEvent.enddate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                        $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                        $('#myModal').modal();
                    },
                    selectable: true,
                    select: function (start, end) {
                        selectedEvent = {
                            eventID: 0,
                            title: '',
                            description: '',
                            startdate: start,
                            enddate: end,
                            color: ''
                        };
                        openAddEditForm();
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    eventDrop: function (event) {
                        var data = {
                            EventID: event.eventID,
                            Title: event.title,
                            StartDate: event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A'),
                            EndDate: event.end != null ? event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A') : null,
                            Description: event.description,
                            ThemeColor: event.color,
                        };
                        SaveEvent(data);
                    }
                })
            }

            $('#btnEdit').click(function () {
                //Open modal dialog for edit event
                openAddEditForm();
            })
            $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
                if (selectedEvent != null && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/home/DeleteEvent',
                        data: { 'eventID': selectedEvent.eventID },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status) {
                                //Refresh the calender
                                FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Failed');
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            $('#dtp1,#dtp2').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'
            });
            function openAddEditForm() {
                if (selectedEvent != null) {
                    $('#hdEventID').val(selectedEvent.eventID);
                    $('#txtTitle').val(selectedEvent.title);
                    $('#txtStartDate').val(selectedEvent.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A'));
                    $('#txtEndDate').val(selectedEvent.end != null ? selectedEvent.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A') : '');
                    $('#txtDescription').val(selectedEvent.description);
                    $('#ddThemeColor').val(selectedEvent.color);
                }
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#myModalSave').modal();
            }
            $('#btnSave').click(function () {
                //Validation/
                if ($('#txtSubject').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('Subject required');
                    return;
                }
                if ($('#txtStart').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('Start date required');
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    var startDate = moment($('#txtStartDate').val(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A").toDate();
                    var endDate = moment($('#txtEndDate').val(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A").toDate();
                    if (startDate > endDate) {
                        alert('Invalid end date');
                        return;
                    }
                }

                var data = {
                    EventID: $('#hdEventID').val(),
                    Subject: $('#txtTitle').val().trim(),
                    Start: $('#txtStartDate').val().trim(),
                    Description: $('#txtDescription').val(),
                    ThemeColor: $('#ddThemeColor').val(),
                }
                SaveEvent(data);
                // call function for submit data to the server
            })
            function SaveEvent(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/home/SaveEvent',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            //Refresh the calender
                            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                            $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    </script>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using FullCalendar.Models;

namespace FullCalendar.Pages.Calendars
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext db;
        
        public IndexModel(DatabaseContext _db)
        {
            db = _db;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
        public IActionResult OnGetFindAllEvents()
        {
            var events = db.MyEvents.Select(v => new
            {
                eventid = v.EventID,
                title = v.Title,
                description = v.Description,
                startdate = v.StartDate.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                enddate = v.EndDate.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                themecolor = v.ThemeColor
            }).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(events);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Models>Calendar.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FullCalendar.Models
{
    public class Calendar
    {
        [Key]
        public int EventID { get; set; }
              
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Column("Title")]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [Column("Description")]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        public DateTime EndtDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [Column("ThemeColour")]
        [Display(Name = "Theme Colour")]
        public string ThemeColour { get; set; }
      
    }
}
```

why the event data is not displayed?

The Console Window showed the following error messages (refer to the attached two screenshots):-
[image: Console window errors part 1]
[image: Console window errors part 2]
[image: wwwroot folder]

Comment: `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` is wrong. fullCalendar accepts only ISO date strings. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing

Comment: @ADyson: thank you for your feedback. I have changed the dates to ISO date string format in the above description. The solution build is still appearing as a blank webpage. When I check the Console window, it is showing some error messages (I have added two images to show the error messages).

Comment: ok. Which of the errors don't you understand? The 404s mean it failed to load any of the files required for the calendar or other scripts. Presumably they don't exist in your project at those locations. The errors which follow are largely the consequences of those download failures, as far as I can see.

Comment: P.S. Also, looking in detail at the HTML, your page appears to be trying to load about 3 different versions of fullCalendar in different places. momentJS is also included 3 times. I haven't started looking at the CSS. I suggest having a serious tidy-up of your links. Check the documentation for the version of fullCalendar you want to use, check what files are needed, and make sure you've a) loaded those correctly, and b) loaded anything else that isn't needed, and c) not loaded the same file more than once.

Comment: Hi @wire_jp, do you put these files within [wwwroot folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows#web-root)? You can share the folder structure of the required js/css files of fullCalendar, so that we can help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: Hi @FeiHan, I added an image of the wwwroot folder to the description. Thanks

Comment: Hi @wire_jp , from the screenshots you provided and the actual code, the structure does not correspond, and some key files are missing, such as `fullcalendar.min.js`, etc. There may be some problems with references to other js files, such as `<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>` should actually be `<script src='~/lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>`, you can try to check the introduction again To ensure that the path is normal.

Answer (score 1):

I made some updates to my app. Firstly, I found that I had two different versions of the FullCalendar.io software installed - fullcalendar v.5.3.0 and fullcalendar v.4.3.0 in the wwwroot directory. So I deleted all of these fullcalendar versions and I installed the current version 5.3.2 from [Full Calendar - Getting Started](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getting-started) as Download zip package. I manually installed in a fullcalendar folder under the wwwroot/lib directory.

[image: FullCalendar installation in wwwroot directory]

I created a Razor page in a folder called Calendars under the Pages Section of the main project solution (i.e. Pages/Calendars/index.cshtml) - index.cshtml in the main project area and I added the following code (using the script tags method as described on this link - [Initialize with Script Tags](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals)): -

```
@page
@model MyApp.Pages.Calendars.IndexModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href='~/lib/fullcalendar/lib/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />    
    <script src='~/lib/fullcalendar/lib/main.js'></script> 

    <script>

         document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
             var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
             var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                 initialVeiw: 'dayGridMonth',
                 headerToolbar: {
                     left: 'prev, next today',
                     center: 'title',
                     right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'                    
                 },
             });
             calendar.render();
         });

     </script> 

    </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output solution, in visual studio, is shown below: -

[image: Full Calendar-Output Solution]